# Как переставить элементы массива в указанном порядке?

Tags: c++, c, массивы

*a<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>n+1</sub>, a<sub>2</sub>, a<sub>n+2</sub>, ... , a<sub>n</sub>, a<sub>2n</sub>*

Задан массив целых чисел *a* размером *2n*. Как сделать перестановку в массиве таким образом?

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Comment: Например, через дополнительный массив :)

Comment: Нужно в том же массиве.

Comment: А быстро или нет? :) Просто можно, например, выполнять сдвиги элемента от конца и до нужного места... Это просто, но O(N^2).

Comment: Можно не быстро.

Comment: Зря закрыли интересный с алгоритмической точки зрения вопрос... Медленно - например, так: https://ideone.com/FeFugR В принципе, можно и быстро, тогда задача распадается на несколько циклов...

Comment: @Harry, вопрос обобщается до "как применить произвольную перестановку за линейное время с константной дополнительной памятью". Ответа я не знаю. Для некоторых видов перестановок задача решена. Если решать во всей общности - тогда интересно.

Comment: Да, даже эта конкретная перестановка интересна сама по себе. Напоминает преобразование пекаря.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Раз устраивает медленный O(N<sup>2</sup>) способ, то просто [поочередно сдвигаем элементы в нужную позицию](https://ideone.com/FeFugR):

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
 
using namespace std;
 
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    const int N = 10;
 
    vector<int> a(2*N);
    for(int i = 0; i < 2*N; ++i) a[i] = i+1;
 
    for(int i = 0; i < 2*N; ++i) cout << a[i] << " "; cout << "\n";
 
    for(int i = N; i <= 2*N-2; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0, k = i; j < 2*N-i-1; ++j,--k)
        {
            swap(a[k],a[k-1]);
        }
    }
 
    for(int i = 0; i < 2*N; ++i) cout << a[i] << " "; cout << "\n";
}
```